# Intellij Is not able to find Jar for running Springboot Application

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am running my spring boot application from Intellij but while running application I am getting following error.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call the method zipkin2.Endpoint$Builder.port(I)Lzipkin2/Endpoint$Builder; but it does not exist. Its class, zipkin2.Endpoint$Builder, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/home/alpesh/.m2/repository/io/zipkin/zipkin2/zipkin/2.7.1/zipkin-2.7.1.jar!/zipkin2/Endpoint$Builder.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/home/alpesh/.m2/repository/io/zipkin/zipkin2/zipkin/2.7.1/zipkin-2.7.1.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of zipkin2.Endpoint$Builder
```

I try to run same from command prompt but got the same error, Then I try to delete from zipkin2.jar from .m2 directory and then application was running from command line, But still not able to run from Intellij

Can someone please help me to figure out this issue.

My Pom.xml is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <name>search-service</name>
    <description>Index Search Service</description>
    <artifactId>search-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
        <artifactId>search</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <core.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</core.version>
        <demo.core.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</demo.core.version>
        <search.core.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</search.core.version>
        <search.client.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</search.client.version>
        <mapstruct.version>1.3.0.Final</mapstruct.version>
        <power-mockito-version>1.7.4</power-mockito-version>
        <entity.share.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</entity.share.version>
        <entity.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</entity.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
            <artifactId>search-client</artifactId>
            <version>${search.client.version}</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
            <artifactId>search-core</artifactId>
            <version>${search.core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>${core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
            <artifactId>entity-core</artifactId>
            <version>${demo.core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
            <artifactId>entity-share</artifactId>
            <version>${entity.share.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
            <artifactId>entity-client</artifactId>
            <version>${entity.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zonky.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedded-database-spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>6.6.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${power-mockito-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>${power-mockito-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thanks
Alpesh

Comment: Are you using `spring-cloud-starter-zipkin` ? Which version?

Comment: Did you manually add zipkin lib to the project classpath in Idea? Check "Project Settings > Libraries" and make sure there is only one entry of the lib which comes from .m2 repo.

Comment: goto Settings ```File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Repositories``` select your repository and update the indexes

Comment: @Villat I have not added any zipkin dependency

Comment: @DirkDeyne I can not see any repository url

Comment: I just got this error when I make RestTemplate of **restTemplate.postForEntity**

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra could you provide us your pom.xml dependencies? If you didn't include zipkin, it's probably related to your dependencies

Comment: @Villat I have updated my question to add  pom.xml.

Comment: @Villat I have also imported multiple maven project modules in same window

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra do you know what are the dependencies that the other projects have?

Comment: @Villat I have created new sprinboot application and past entire pom.xml of old project, now this is working, I also check the effective POM in intellij, here I can not see the zipkin2 dependency. Do you have any idea which springboot jar is dependent on zipkin ?